# Windows API for DNS change notification

Tags: c++, c, winapi, network-programming

I am looking for a way to receive a notification whenever the configured DNS server address of a network interface changes, using native Windows APIs (C/C++). For both performance and reaction time reasons, I'd obviously want to avoid polling.

There is, for example, the [`NotifyIpInterfaceChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-notifyipinterfacechange) API in `Iphlpapi.dll`.  In my tests, it reliably triggers a notification when the host's IP address, subnet mask, or default gateway changes, but not at all when only the DNS addresses change.

My only "solution" up to this point is using WMI event queries, but it actually polls in the background, so to avoid hogging down the system, the polling interval (WQL `WITHIN` clause) needs to be set to several seconds, which results in a long and annoying delay for my application. Also, for various reasons (which are not the topic of this discussion), I prefer to avoid WMI usage anyway, resorting to it only when there is no other way.

Comment: how minimum possible call [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue)  on `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces[\interface-name]` because this key will be changed when DNS server(s) changed - [*NameServer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978468(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [*DhcpNameServer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc962470(v=technet.10))

Comment: Good idea. I researched it a bit, and it should work. I can definitely see this as an acceptable solution. I just wonder if this is the only way? It sure is better than WMI IMHO.

Comment: *if this is the only way?* dont know. possible exist and better solution/api for this, but i dont know about this. better that WMI - yes, 100%

Comment: Yes, I only meant I'll wait a bit more if somebody else shows up with a maybe even better idea. In the meantime, if you put yours in an answer instead of a comment, I'll gladly upvote it. And if nothing better shows up, I'll glaldy accept it as the answer.

Comment: @RbMm: I'd like to accept your suggestion as the solution. Can you put it into an answer? Then you'll get the points for it.

Comment: @ultimA  Hi, you can post answer to end the thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual credit for this answer should go to RbMm, but he's not posting the answer and seems to have gone MIA.

To receive DNS change notifications, the only non-polling solution seems to be using the `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` WinApi to monitor for changes under the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip[6]\Parameters\Interfaces` key. Note that there's separate Tcpip and Tcpip6 keys for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively. Anyway, I've implemented and thoroughly tested the solution since the original suggestion and it works without problems.

A semi-related warning: `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` has its non-intuitive peculiarities, and it is unlike most other notification APIs, so be sure to study its docs.